# Use COPY to import a csv in a table with counters in Cassandra

Tags: csv, cassandra, cql, cqlsh

I am trying to import a csv dump in my cassandra table using the `copy` command.
It works fine except for tables which contain counter column.

For these tables I get the following error message:

```
code=2200 [Invalid query] message="INSERT statement are not allowed on counter tables, use UPDATE instead"
```

Is there a workaround here? How can I bulk import the data from my csv file in my table?

Many thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [documentation on the COPY command](http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cql/3.1/cql/cql_reference/copy_r.html) is pretty clear on this one:

> You cannot copy data to or from counter tables.

As mentioned in this similar question([How can a CSV file with counter columns be loaded to a Cassandra CQL3 table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21112166/how-can-a-csv-file-with-counter-columns-be-loaded-to-a-cassandra-cql3-table)), you can load tables with counter columns using the [sstableloader](https://www.datastax.com/documentation/cassandra/2.1/cassandra/tools/toolsBulkloader_t.html).

There does not appear to be a ticket addressing this problem in the [Cassandra JIRA project](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/cassandra/?selectedTab=com.atlassian.jira.jira-projects-plugin:issues-panel), either.  You are welcome to create one, but there are some underlying issues that would make this difficult (basically, `COPY TO` also uses CQL and would also be subject to the restriction about setting a specific counter value vs. incrementing it).

**EDIT 20180525**

As of [CASSANDRA-9043](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-9043) tables with counter columns should now work with the COPY command.

Comment: This came along shortly after this answer was posted: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-9043
It's been resolved and COPY works with counter tables now.

Comment: @AdamHolmberg Thanks for the tip!  Edit made.